# After clicking popup button I want to display some text on the webpage. But not working, any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, dom

After clicking popup button I want to display some text on the webpage. But not working, any suggestions?

I am no javascript expert, but I am learning.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var showMessage = "";
        window.onload = function(){
            if (confirm("Your Details have been Saved.")) {
                showMessage = "Please wait .. going to viewProfile";
                window.location.assign("viewProfile.php");
            } else {
                showMessage = "Please wait ..";    
                window.location.assign("editProfile.php");
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body id="save-profile-page">
        <script type="text/javascript">    
            document.writeln(showMessage);
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the messages dont display for some reason, please help.

Comment: why dont you try alert ?

Comment: seem to be managing redirects in wrong environment. Doesn't make any sense for user to confirm `details saved` as soon as page loads. Should be managing redirect at server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variable `showMessage` is empty until after the javascript function is run, which is AFTER the document has already loaded. Instead, create a function and call it in your `HTML` in place of

```
function callConfirm(){
    if(confirm("...?")){
        document.writeln("Message1…");
    }
    else{
        document.writeln("Message2…");
    }
}
```

Call it in your `HTML`

```
<script>
    callConfirm();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, it worked. your a genius, which me luck in my learning quest.

Answer (score 0):

As @mavili says, showMessage is not yet defined when you try to print it. However, there is a more serious logical problem with this code. The variable showMessage is assigned in the same scope as the redirect. As soon as the redirect call is reached the new page loads, so there's no chance for the message to be displayed, even if you re-arrange the code.